# Use PUT method with ajax Knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, knockout.js

I have a `div` with text, when I click on that `div` the `input` field appears and I can edit text. Then when I click elsewhere the changes are applied. 
I want to use `PUT` method with ajax to send updated value to database, but how can I trigger an event when my item is edited?
My View looks like this:

```
<div class="set_info" data-bind="foreach: sets">
<div data-bind="visible: !editing(), text: name, click: edit"></div>
<input class = "edit_set" data-bind="visible: editing, value: name, hasFocus: editing" /></div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a subscription on `name` or add an `event: {change: dosomething}` binding to the `input`. I'd be more inclined to do the former based on separation of concerns (the view itself shouldn't have to know which elements cause a trip to the server when they're changed). Another option is to make `name` a read/write computed observable, but that's probably more work.